# Bounded Homeomorphism and its inverse

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

Can someone help with an explanation on how to about this question.

Let ϕ:Rn→Rn be a homeomorphism of the form $ϕ(x)=x+h(x)$ with bounded h. Show that $ϕ^{−1}(x)=x+k(x)$, where k(x) is again bounded (with the same bound).

Comment: Problem 9.14 in Ordinary Differential Equations by Teschl.

Answer (score 1):

$$\phi^{-1}(x)-x= \phi^{-1}(x)-\phi( \phi^{-1}(x))=-h(\phi^{-1}(x))
$$

Define
$$k(x):=-h(\phi^{-1}(x))$$